# Left Outer Join - how to detect null?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var tt = (from m in mixed
                  join s in _dbContext.Store_Doc_StockReqItem
                  on new { m.StoreReqFileNo, m.StoreReqItemKeyID }
                  equals new { s.StoreReqFileNo, s.StoreReqItemKeyID } into ms
                  from s in ms.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  where m.StoreReqFileNo == id
                  group new { m, s } by new
                  {
                      m.StoreReqItemKeyID
                  } into g
                  select new
                  {
                      StoreReqFileNo = g.Max(p => p.m.StoreReqFileNo),
                      g.Key.StoreReqItemKeyID,
                      StockID = g.Max(p => p.m.StockID),
                      Description = g.Max(p => p.m.Description),
                      EstateID = g.Max(p => p.m.EstateID),
                      DivisionID = g.Max(p => p.m.DivisionID),
                      BlockID = g.Max(p => p.m.BlockID),
                      JobCodeID = g.Max(p => p.m.JobCodeID),
                      UOMID = g.Max(p => p.m.UOMID),
                      Total = (decimal?)(g.Max(p => p.m.Total)),
                      Balance = (decimal?)(g.Max(p => p.m.Balance)),
                      Available = g.Max(p => p.s.Quantity) == null ? g.Max(p => p.s.Quantity) : 0
                  }).ToList();
```

How to detect the Available from the Table if after join it is null or not. If it's null set to 0 else get the decimal number from database

return Json(tt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: I think you want `g.Max(p => p.s?.Quantity ?? 0)`

Comment: `p.s` (via group on `{..s}`) will be “Default” (ie. null) “If Empty”.

Comment: Thanks a lot John!!! It helps me to clear my doubt from the past 3 weeks that I couldn't solve ^_^ appreciate your help very much!!